# Hide element with CSS if it has no child element

Tags: html, css

I have a header bar and this contains 3 div elements. If the width of the screen is smaller than x I want to hide the first container **and** the second one if this contains no element.

So I went for this

https://jsfiddle.net/5x8bdd51/

---

```css
#parent {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
}

#c1 {
  background: red;
}

#c2 {
  background: green;
}

#c3 {
  background: blue;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
  .container:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="container" id="c1">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="c2">

  </div>
  <div class="container" id="c3">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the first and the second container will hide on smaller screens. But how can I make the second container only hide if it is empty?

**Pseudo Code**

```
  .container:nth-child(2) @if :empty {
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: `.container:nth-child(2):empty {
    display: none;
  }`

Comment: sorry that did not work, nothing happens then

Comment: depends if you want to support IE8. And be careful to remove spaces.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty Whitespace is considered content, thus making an element non-empty.

Comment: oh well, I removed the whitespace, now it works

Comment: try this `div:empty { display: none }` for the all div

Comment: you can use .container:nth-child(2):empty `#parent .container:nth-child(2):empty {
    display: none;
}`  like : https://jsfiddle.net/5x8bdd51/2/